# using add_role function to make some users to create a selected type post 

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

how are you ?

I have in my site (post_type called = books)..

I need to make some users for example (Library) to create a books (post_type = books) ..

this is the code to add rols (called = library) ..

```
$library = add_role('library', 'library', array(
    'read' => true, 
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false, 
));
```

The library Role can create (any type of post) , I want it to create books (post_type) ..

I wish you understand me ..

thank you very much ^_^

Comment: @hakre thank you very much. I have problem with the dots because I'm using dots in my language and no problem with using. But I this in English is big problem. The two  dots mean end of sentenece.I will don't using again in next time.

Comment: @hakre I will write the question by change it. In my website I added a new post type. it is books(by using register post type function). afterthat , I need type or role for user. There are some of types (Super Admin , Administrator , Editor , Author ,Contributor and Subscriber). I need to add new role or new type ( for example: Employers). I want to give this type(employers) some roles like: write books , not post or page. just books(books: new type post). BUT HOW? If you can't understand to me. I will change again. Thanks hakre ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own capabilities for custom post types. The default behvaiour for a post type is to inherit capabilities from the default post post-type.

See the capabilities parameter in [register_post_type (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), that has more information about how that can be done.